# Xcode upload for TestFlight - do I need a distribution provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm new to iOS development, and I'm at the step where I'd like to beta test my app. In looking at the [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35) for TestFlight, I ran across this:

> Important:  In order to use iTunes Connect for TestFlight beta testing, you must submit your app using the latest App Store Distribution profiles that contain the beta entitlement. To regenerate your App Store distribution profile, visit the Member Center.

And in the [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH36-SW2) for uploading an app, I found this:

> A store provisioning profile is a distribution provisioning profile that authorizes your app to use certain app services and ensures that you are the one uploading your app. A store provisioning profile contains a single App ID that matches one or more of your apps and a distribution certificate. You configure the App ID indirectly through Xcode to use certain app services. You enable and configure app services by setting entitlements and performing other configuration steps. Some entitlements are enabled for an App ID (a set of apps created by your team), and others are set in the Xcode project. When you upload your app to the store, Xcode signs the app bundle with the distribution certificate referenced in the store provisioning profile.

[image: store provisioning image]

I currently have one iOS Development Provisioning Profile, one App ID, and two Certificates (one Development and one Distribution), but no distribution profiles. Before uploading to iTunes Connect, I'd like to make sure I'm not missing any steps.

1. What are "App Store Distribution profile" and "store provisioning profile"? Are they the same thing, and do I need to create it in Member Center?  Or does Xcode or iTunes Connect combine my existing App ID and Distribution Certificate into a Distribution Profile behind the scenes?
2. What is a "beta entitlement". I looked at my App ID and Xcode settings, and couldn't find anything related to beta.
3. The image above shows "Development Certificate", but the description above says "distribution certificate referenced in the store provisioning profile". I assume the latter is correct?

Comment: I never used test flight myself. I've been using Crashlytics for a while. But AFAIK, for question one, yes, they are the same and you need to create then in member centre or using Xcode. For question three, if you need to distribute your app either for testing or for submitting, you'll have to use distribution certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successfully uploading my app for testing and getting it into the hands of beta testers, I've concluded the following.

1. Yes, both "App Store Distribution profile" and "store provisioning profile" are the same. I didn't have to create either one. When Xcode uploaded my app, it said it was using a profile called "XC", which I didn't have to create. I think the existence of my App ID and Distribution Certificate was sufficient.
2. I didn't have to enable anything called "beta entitlement", and my testers were able to use the app after installing via TestFlight.
3. I think the image should say "Distribution Certificate", not "Development Certificate".